# update join with case mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm using Mysql and I'm having a difficult time trying to get the results from a update query. I am having 2 tables. First table loaddata_temp and second table section company_category

first table loaddata_temp

```
|id_external|company_name               |company_category_id|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|          1|iqballord                  |UD                 |
|          2|A Plus Lawn Care           |PT                 |
|          3|A. L. Price                |PMA                |
|          4|A.J. August Fashion Wear   |BUMN               |
|          5|A+ Electronics             |WARUNG             | 
|          6|A+ Investments             |PT                 |
```

second Table Company_category

```
|company_category_id|company_category_description|
--------------------|-----------------------------
|                  3|PT                          |
|                  5|UD                          |
|                  6|PMA                         |
|                  7|BUMN                        |
|                 23|Koperasi                    |
```

I used this query to get results as

```
UPDATE loaddata_temp,company_category
       SET loaddata_temp.company_category_id= 
        CASE 
            WHEN loaddata_temp.company_category_id = company_category.company_category_description 
            THEN company_category.company_category_id
            ELSE 'error' END
```

what i expeted from above query

```
|id_external|company_name               |company_category_id|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|          1|iqballord                  |5                  |
|          2|A Plus Lawn Care           |3                  |
|          3|A. L. Price                |6                  |
|          4|A.J. August Fashion Wear   |7                  |
|          5|A+ Electronics             |error              | 
|          6|A+ Investments             |3                  |
```

but what i get

```
|id_external|company_name               |company_category_id|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|          1|iqballord                  |error              |
|          2|A Plus Lawn Care           |error              |
|          3|A. L. Price                |error              |
|          4|A.J. August Fashion Wear   |error              |
|          5|A+ Electronics             |error              | 
|          6|A+ Investments             |3                  |
```

Comment: why you are using update...instead of select?!

Comment: i need to check when i imported using  load local data in file which row not related with company_category.


do you have any suggestion or best way to do it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following query:

```
UPDATE      loaddata_temp lt
LEFT JOIN   company_category cc
        ON  cc.company_category_description = lt.company_category_id
    SET     lt.company_category_id = COALESCE(cc.company_category_id, 'error');
```

Use LEFT JOIN to find matching rows for update. If no row was found in company_category table then update to 'error'.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE loaddata_temp l LEFT JOIN company_category c ON c.company_category_description = l.company_category_id
       SET loaddata_temp.company_category_id= If(c.company_category_id IS NULL, 'error' ,c.company_category_id)
```

you can also use IF statement in query if company_category_id found then it will update the same otherwise return 'error'.